# Remove custom cursor on touch screen

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, custom-cursor

I have a custom cursor that I implemented using some JS found on here. It work's perfectly - BUT, I need to turn it off on touch screens, otherwise it just sits on the screen as a big yellow dot.

Unfortunately, apart from the inline styles, I don't understand the JS enough to edit it to achieve this.

This is the JS

```
$("body").append('<div class="cursor"></div>');
$("html").append('<style>html, body, .msty_notcur {cursor:none !important;}.cursor {z-index:10000000000000; mix-blend-mode: difference; position: fixed;background-color:#FDFF07; width:25px;height:25px;border-radius:100%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);top:0px;left:0px;pointer-events:none; -webkit-transition: width 200ms, height 300ms; -webkit-transition: height 200ms, width:300ms; } .overlink {width:45px;height:45px; -webkit-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms; -webkit-transition: height 200ms, width:200ms;} .overtext {background-color:rgba(100,100,255,0.25) !important;border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,100,0.25) !important;}</style>');
var scrollY = 0, scrollX = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   $(".cursor").css("top",e.pageY - scrollY + "px").css("left",e.pageX - scrollX + "px");
});
$(document).scroll(function(e){
   scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
   scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
});
setInterval(function(){scroll = $(window).scrollTop();}, 1000);
$("*").hover(function(e){
   var index = -1;
   try {
      index = $(this).attr("class").toLowerCase().indexOf("button");
      if (index == -1) {
         index = $(this).attr("class").toLowerCase().indexOf("link");
      }
   }
   catch(e) {
      index = -1;
   }
   if($(this).css("cursor") == "pointer" || $(this).get(0).tagName == "A" || $(this).get(0).tagName == "BUTTON" || $(this).hasClass("msty_cur") || index > -1) {
      $(this).addClass("msty_cur");
      $(this).css("cursor","none");
      $(".cursor").addClass("overlink");
   }
   if($(this).css("cursor") != "none") {
      $(this).addClass("msty_notcur")
   }
}, function(e){
   $(this).css("cursor","none");
   $(".cursor").removeClass("overlink");
});
```

And the website where it is implemented is [here](https://www.shereewalker.com/)

The difficulty I have with using just CSS is applying the mix-blend-mode to the cursor

Comment: Any reason you are not using css for custom cursors? Those are typically hidden on touch only interfaces

Comment: What about detecting a `touchstart` event and in its handler setting the cursor's `display` to `none`?

Comment: Do they get CSS to do Javascript tasks as well?

Comment: @ferrybig I would have preferred using CSS and initially I tried using an SVG as the cursor, but it just would not work, a png did but the quality looked a bit poor. When I dug into it deeper, I found this JS - I assumed that a person with this level of JS would have a legitimate reason for using it to achieve this task so I went with it.

I will try again using CSS to get a better result.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve a circle without using a png/svg/image? In perhaps the same way you would a psuedo?

Comment: Actually now that I have changed it to css I realise the reason was because I could not apply a mix-blend-mode to the cursor - hence why I used JS.

Comment: @CodeUK - perhaps you have a solution to this where I can use CSS AND have a mix-blend-mode applied to the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, your best bet is to try and detect the screen size. It looks like [768 is a safe bet for max-width](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

You'd want to add both a conditional statement (for when the page loads) `onresize` for the document. I'd also wrap the cursor creation into a function for re-usability/convenience.

```js
customCursor = () => {
  $("body").append('<div class="cursor"></div>');
  $("html").append('<style>.cursor {z-index:10000000000000; mix-blend-mode: difference; position: fixed;background-color:#FDFF07; width:25px;height:25px;border-radius:100%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);top:0px;left:0px;pointer-events:none; -webkit-transition: width 200ms, height 300ms; -webkit-transition: height 200ms, width:300ms; } .overlink {width:45px;height:45px; -webkit-transition: width 300ms, height 300ms; -webkit-transition: height 200ms, width:200ms;} .overtext {background-color:rgba(100,100,255,0.25) !important;border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,100,0.25) !important;}</style>');

  var scrollY = 0,
    scrollX = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $(".cursor").css("top", e.pageY - scrollY + "px").css("left", e.pageX - scrollX + "px");
  });
  $(document).scroll(function(e) {
    scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  }, 1000);
  $("*").hover(function(e) {
    var index = -1;

    try {

      index = $(this).attr("class").toLowerCase().indexOf("button");
      if (index == -1) {
        index = $(this).attr("class").toLowerCase().indexOf("link");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      index = -1;
    }
    if ($(this).css("cursor") == "pointer" || $(this).get(0).tagName == "A" || $(this).get(0).tagName == "BUTTON" || $(this).hasClass("msty_cur") || index > -1) {

      $(this).addClass("msty_cur");
      $(this).css("cursor", "none");
      $(".cursor").addClass("overlink");
    }
    if ($(this).css("cursor") != "none") {
      $(this).addClass("msty_notcur")
    }
  }, function(e) {
    $(this).css("cursor", "none");
    $(".cursor").removeClass("overlink");
  });
}

if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.cursor = 'default'
} else {
  customCursor()
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    var cursor = $(".cursor")
    cursor.remove()
    $('body').css({
      cursor: "default",
    })
  } else {
    $('body').css({
      cursor: "none",
    })
    customCursor()
  }
});
```

Honestly, your best bet is to utilize CSS more as opposed to using jQuery to append/manipulate things but that's up to you.

Comment: Hi there - thanks very much for this time and effort. As you and others have said, I will re attempt this with CSS. I found the tutorial online after being unsuccessful with CSS and assumed it was a typical approach.

Comment: Actually now that I have changed it to css I realise the reason was because I could not apply a mix-blend-mode to the cursor - hence why I used JS. – M